# How do you get a list of indexes with certain criteria in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a Dataframe with non-negative values throughout, but the missing values have been encoded as negative. I want to get all those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df.index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[-4,5,4,5,5,-4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,-7,1,0],
         'E':[5,-3,6,9,2,4],

})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0 -4  7  1  5
1  5  8  3 -3
2  4  9  5  6
3  5  4 -7  9
4  5  2  1  2
5 -4  3  0  4

idx = df.index[df.lt(0).any(axis=1)]
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 5], dtype='int64')
```

**Explanation**:

First compare all values by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) (`<`):

(similar functions are [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html), 
[`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.le.html), 
[`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html), 
[`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html), 
[`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html))

```
print (df.lt(0))
       B      C      D      E
0   True  False  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True  False
4  False  False  False  False
5   True  False  False  False
```

And then check at least one `True` value per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df.lt(0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is there anyway I could apply this to a column, so I know where those values are . More precisely, I want to bin all non-negative values but qcut returns Nan where there's negative values , so I need to be able to put back the negative values

Comment: @drotsky - Sorry, so what is expected output from my sample? Please create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the row-wise minimum and check if it is less than 0:

```
res = df.index[df.min(1) < 0]

# data from @jezrael    
# Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 5], dtype='int64')
```